# Finding orthogonal complement and projection

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality

Please, may i ask you to help me check if i solved next problem correctly?

The problem:

(a) Find the solution of the next system of the linear equations: 
$$ x + 2y + 3z + 4t = 1, $$
$$ 2x + 7y + 8z + 11t = 2, $$
$$ -3x - 6y - 8z - 10t = 3, $$
$$ x + 3y + 4z + 6t = 4, $$
$$ 4x + 9y + 11z + 14t = -5. $$
Find a directrix $W$ of the linear manifold defined by the given system.

(b) Find an orthogonal complement ofthe $W$ and find an orthogonal projection of the vector $(1, 0, 0, 1)$ on the subspace $W$.

Although the text of the problem doesn't explicitly states that everything happens in vector space $\Bbb{R}^4$, i think that's clear beacuse of the given vector $(1, 0, 0, 1)$.

My solution:

(a) I found that the solution of the system is unique vector $(-5, -3, 0, 3)$. That implies that the system defines the next linear manifold: $L = (-5, -3, -, 7) + \alpha(0, 0, 0, 0)$. So, the directrix of that linear manifold is subspace $W = \{ 0\}$.

(b) Now, the orthogonal complement of the directrix $W$ is another trivial subspace, $W^{\bot} = \Bbb{R}^4$. If $x \in W$, $y \in W^{\bot}$ and $\alpha,  \beta \in \Bbb{R}$ are such that $(1, 0, 0, 1) = \alpha x + \beta y$, than we have:
$$(1, 0, 0, 1) = \alpha (0, 0, 0, 0) + \beta (x_1, x_2, x_3, x-4).$$
Now, $\beta$ must be different form $0$, becuase otherwise will be $(1, 0, 0, 1) \neq \alpha x + \beta y$.
From there we can see that orthogonal projection of $(1, 0, 0, 1)$ on $W$ is null-vector.

Comment: You can check the solution of the system yourself by typing it into wolfram alpha (btw, what is the third equation? you are missing a $\pm$ there). If the solution is wrong, then all subsequent answers will be wrong.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! The smallest problem i have is the system (i checked it in wolfram alpha and the solution is good). I was worried about orthogonal complement and projection, because i never, until now, worked with subspace containing only null-vector.

Comment: Well, according to this solver (http://wims.unice.fr/wims/en_tool~linear~linsolver.en.html), your system doesn't have a solution. The vector $(-5,-3,0,3)$ doesn't solve the last equation because $4(-5) + 9(-3) + 14 \cdot 3 = -47 + 42 = -5 \neq -2$.

Comment: I'm sorry for that mistake. I wrote the original text of the problem, but the system than doesn't have solution and the rest of the problem becomes irrelevant. I made a correction. I will be more careful next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is correct although it is strange that the system has a single solution because the following questions become trivial. Indeed, the orthogonal projection of a vector onto the zero subspace is the zero vector (there is no other choice for the orthogonal projection must belong to the subspace). Also, the orthogonal complement of the zero subspace is the whole space.